# How to determine height of the Display on Blackberry touch devices?

Tags: blackberry, screen, screen-resolution

I trying to determine display vertical size of my Blackberry Storm 2.

I know, my device has 480 pixels height. I try to get this value in my code, but if virtual keyboard is shown, i get value equals to **480 - (height of virtual keyboard)**. Is there any function to determine **real** display height on any device (with or without keyboard, with enabled or disabled virtual keyboard).

Im also discover RIM classes:

I get these values with hidden virtual keyboard:

```
Display.getWidth(); //360
Display.getHeight(); //480
UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen().getContentWidth(); //360
UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen().getContentHeight(); //480
UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen().getWidth(); //360
UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen().getHeight(); //480
UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen().getVirtualWidth(); //360
UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen().getVirtualHeight(); //480
UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen().getVisibleWidth(); //360
UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen().getVisibleHeight(); //480
```

I get these values with showed virtual keyboard:

```
Display.getWidth(); //360
Display.getHeight(); //248
UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen().getContentWidth(); //360
UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen().getContentHeight(); //248
UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen().getWidth(); //360
UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen().getHeight(); //248
UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen().getVirtualWidth(); //360
UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen().getVirtualHeight(); //248
UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen().getVisibleWidth(); //360
UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen().getVisibleHeight(); //248
```

Is there any way to determine real screen height?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would like to know workaround too

In the meantime you can store size of display for different devices and retrieve them depending on [DeviceInfo.getDeviceName()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/system/DeviceInfo.html#getDeviceName%28%29)

Or you can save [Display.getHeight()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Display.html#getHeight%28%29) value on app start

Comment: +1 on reading and saving the Display.getHeight() on app startup (before a virtual keyboard is shown).  This is what we do with our app.

Comment: I already did exactly as you said, cause i didn't find solution.
I define a resolution depending on the device name.
Please post quick solution there if you find it. Thnx for discussion.

Comment: You're welcome! Remember to switch height & width on orientation change in storm!